# Ember. Lazy loading templates and javascript for really big apps

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm studying a bit of ember and I like it so far. The problem I have with ember (and most frameworks I saw, both server and client side) is that almost all tutorials and guides are designed for small apps (as TodoMVC). I'm interested about how to handle huge administrative apps (like 30 or 40 pages, or more). That reason made me go for framework-less apps many times. What I saw is that you can use Yeoman or another tool to build a single js file and html. Most people focus in how to split the code in development and it's okay. I want to ask you how to divide the code that is downloaded at runtime. I think (maybe I'm outdated) that the users of administrative apps don't have to wait for the load of the whole app. They use 4 or 5 pages of the whole stack most of the time. I read briefly about require.js but ember doesn't advocate using it. What I need is a way of lazy load templates and javascript code like routers, controllers, etc.
How do you guys manage apps like those I mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

There is a great blog post from @mixonic on this topic. It explains how you can use a before hook in the router to lazy-load scripts for one or more routes in your application. This technique can be used to lazy-load any application code including routes/controllers/models/templates or third party libraries.

http://madhatted.com/2013/6/29/lazy-loading-with-ember

Comment: I just read the post. It's awesome! Many thanks Mike. Just what I need.

Comment: Be aware that Ember will have [generated an registered the routes!](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2947)!

Comment: This. If you are trying to lazily register routes with the app, you'll have to `App.__container__.unregister('route:blah');` the auto-generated route and then be sure your resolver can load the newly fetched implementation.